# Why does my js modal not close when I click outside?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I am attempting to create a photo gallery, where the pictures can be clicked to reveal a modal describing the picture. The close button works, however, I need to be able to click outside, on the background, to close the modal as well. I have the following code:

```js
function stylemodals() {
  var modalarray = document.body.getElementsByClassName("modal");
  for (var i = 0; i < modalarray.length; i++) {
    modalarray[i].setAttribute("style", "display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; color:black; overflow: auto; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);");
  }
}
stylemodals();

function stylemodalcontent() {
  var modalcontentarray =
    document.body.getElementsByClassName("modal-content");

  for (var i = 0; i < modalcontentarray.length; i++) {
    modalcontentarray[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 15 % auto; border: 1 px solid #888;width: 70%;");
  }
}
stylemodalcontent();
//set 1
var mdl1 = document.getElementById('mdl1');
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var close1 = document.getElementById("close1");
btn1.onclick = function() {
  mdl1.style.display = "block";
};
close1.onclick = function() {
  mdl1.style.display = "none";
};
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == mdl1) {
    mdl1.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal NEEDS AN IMAGE -->
            <input type="image" src="" alt="ib-image" id="btn1">

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="mdl1" class="modal">
                <!-- Modal content NEEDS CONTENT-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span id="close1" style="color: rgb(31, 31, 31); float: right; 
                font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold;">&times;</span>
                    <p>CONTENT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have been researching how to do this, I copied and pasted this from w3schools, and then modified it to my needs, but I still cannot click outside the modal to close. How do I do this?

--EDIT--

here is the new code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
modal.setAttribute("style", "display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: black; overflow: auto; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); ");
 
document.getElementById("modal-content").setAttribute("style", "background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 15% auto; border: 1px solid #888; width: 70%;");
 
var actualmodalcontent = document.getElementById("actual-modal-content");
function modal1 (){
 actualmodalcontent.innerHTML = "CONTENT1"
 modal.style.display = "block";
};
var close = document.getElementById("close");
window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
     }
    if (event.target == close) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="modal">
 <div id="modal-content">
  <span id="close" onclick="close()" style="color: rgb(31, 31, 31); float: right; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold;">&times;</span>

  <p id="actual-modal-content">
   CONTENT0
  </p>
 </div>
</div>

<input type="image" src="" alt="ib-image" id="btn1" onclick="modal1()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked your website, your entire problem is with the fact you have a lot of models and you are registering over 10 different click events on the window object, the only click event that will be actually registered is the last, the rest just override each other.

whenever you do this

```
window.onclick = function() {};
// Or
window['onclick'] = function() {};
```

what you are doing is just simple assignment to an object's property, that object being the window object.

the best solution to your problem is making one model and modify it's content based on whatever button the user has clicked.

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you

Comment: The modal closes when i click outside, but now the close button and content do not work, see the edit

Comment: actually, scratch that, the window part works, but not the close button

Comment: You didn't write the function and you were calling it i'm talking about the 'close()' function.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == mdl1) {
    mdl1.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

That part of the code will set the modals display to none if one clicks exactly upon the modal, not outside of it.
So you need to use `event.target !== mdl1 && !mdl1.contains( event.target )` to detect clicks upon any element on the page that is not the modal itsself, or any of its children. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Keep in mind that you might want to only add the close handler to the window once a modal is actually open and then remove it once the modal gets closed. That way you can prevent your page firing several onclick events for modals that might not even be rendered.

Comment: I have that, and it works in this environment, but it doesn't work in production

Comment: Do you get an error? Any clue why it does not work in production? If it works here, but not on your PC, there must be differences in the code that break it.

Comment: no error, but this is a bit of a set of 12 in a table, if you want to see it it is [here](https://galvantua.github.io/IBWebsite/gallery.html)